# Dynamic update of an Object

Tags: apex

I have two object one is  "Address" and other is used to update the address "UpdateAddress". UpdateAddress has lookup relation ship with Address.
Based on Approval it needs to update the Address.
Suppose I have one field City in Address object and New City in UpdateAddress object when a record in UpdateAddress is Approved it should automatically update the Address.
My question is how to perform this updation dynamically like if in future I add 'New Street' in UpdateAddress it should update the Street field in Address object
without changing my code. 
I am trying to do this by custom setting

Any kind of help is Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can invent your own syntax in custom setting strings to define the fields and then use [split](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_split) or [JSON.deserialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserialize) to access the data in your code. You may have to use multiple fields because each one can only hold 255 characters.

Instead of custom settings you might also choose to use [field sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm).

When you have the API names of the fields, the [get](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get) and [put](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_put) methods can be invoked on any SObject to make the changes without being locked to specific field names at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers to update dynamically the object in the code i have use only imaginary fields as per you question if you want to test this trigger than use the fileds same as in your Objects.

```
    trigger AccountUpdate on UpdateAddress (after insert, after update) {
    list<Address> al = new list<Address>();
    for(UpdateAddress u : Trigger.new ){

        Addres a= new Address();
        a=[select city__c from Address where id =: u.Address__c];      
        a.City__c =  ct.New_City__c;
        al.add(a);
    }
    update al;
}
```

Comment: by this way if in future if I need to add Street in UpdateAddress object in future then I need to change my code. I want to do it without changing the code like by custom setting or by any other possible way.